# Merging two pcap files with libpcap

Tags: pcap, libpcap, winpcap

I already know how to read a pcap file and get the packets it have.B ut how can I write the packets into a new pcap file? I need this to merge two pcap files into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, libpcap/WinPcap is a library, not a program, so to use libpcap/WinPcap to merge capture files, you'd have to write your own code to do the merging, using libpcap/WinPcap to read the input files and write the output files.

You could use an existing tool, such as tracemerge or Wireshark's mergecap, to merge the captures.

Assuming the goal is to merge two files' packets by time stamp, then, if you wanted to write your own code, you'd:

- attempt to open the two files, and fail if you can't;
- if the two files have different link-layer header types or snapshot lengths, fail (you'd have to write a pcap-ng file to handle that, and libpcap/WinPcap don't support that yet);
- if the files have the same link-layer header types and snapshot lengths, open an output file using one of the `pcap_t`s (it doesn't matter which one; all the `pcap_t` does is tell `pcap_dump_open()` what link-layer header type and snapshot length to use);

and have a loop where you:

- if there's no packet already read from the first file, and the first file is still open, read a packet from it - if that gets an EOF, close the first file;
- if there's no packet already read from the second file, and the second file is still open, read a packet from it - if that gets an EOF, close the second file;
- if you have two packets, write out the one with the older time stamp and mark that packet as no longer being there, so you read another packet from the file from which it came;
- if you have only one packet, write it out and mark it as no longer being there, so you read another packet from the file from which it came;
- if you have no packets, you're done - exit the loop;

and then, when you exit the loop, close the dump file.  At that point, you're done.

Comment: I'm try to simply merge two .pcap files without sorting the packet order. I got a  problem that the merged file loses many information including source,destination,protocol,length,etc.

Comment: I used pcap_loop and pcap_dump to do that, should I instead use any other functions to do so or I just used it in a wrong way? I can't paste my code here so if u can write a really simple example about how to use pcap_loop and pcap_dump to merge two pcap files I'll appreciate it terribly!

Comment: Well, if you have two sets of packets that you want to merge into a single file, you have to *somehow* decide which packets go where in the resulting file.  If you *don't* care about the packet order, you could read all the packets from one file, using, for example, `pcap_loop()`, and write them to the file using `pcap_dump()`, and then read all the packets from the other file, using `pcap_loop()`, and write them to the file using `pcap_dump()`.  I don't have time to write the program for you, so you'll have to use that to figure out what code to write.

Comment: I found out that I used a wrong argument in the 'pcap_loop()', now there is nothing wrong with merging any two .pcap files by my code and the new file doesn't lose any data . thank you so much.

Comment: Hi.For a correct merge *.pcap files use https://github.com/wkoroy/tcpmerge/  utility

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `joincap`.

```
go get -u github.com/assafmo/joincap
```

To merge `1.pcap` and `2.pcap`:

```
joincap 1.pcap 2.pcap > merged.pcap
```

I wrote `joincap` to overcome what I believe is bad error handling by `mergecap` and `tcpslice`.
For more details go to https://github.com/assafmo/joincap.

Comment: I tried to install it in `Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows`  (ubuntu terminal installed from microsoft store) and all looks good with no errors but when try to send the command `joincap`  appears `command not found`.

Comment: You probably need to add it to your PATH